# Insurance for UK residents living abroad

Tags: insurance

Health insurance for ex-pats abroad? I am thinking of buying a house abroad (outside Europe) and living there for probably 9 months of the year and back here for the other 3 months. I would rent out my house in the UK and stay with friends when I returned to UK. My holiday insurance says I should be 'permanently resident in UK'to qualify. How do you define 'permanently resident'?

1. I`m still on the voters roll.
2. I`m registered with a GP.
3. I have a bank account here.
4. I am an OAP here.
5. I pay taxes here.
6. I am British.
7. This is my home country.
8. I just choose to have a holiday home abroad and holiday abroad for 9 months of the year.

So am I 'permanently resident' here?

Comment: Holiday insurance is not really meant for what you wanting to do. Look closely at that policy coverage. It would almost certainly have a clause that voids it for the circumstances you are describing. That's what you should be worried about. It's likely your living style would retain your residency in the eye of the UK government, but if you want health insurance for when you abroad most of the year, you should look at policies for just exactly that. I've heard of international sales people at my company taking out such policies, so they must exist.

Answer (score 2):

The NHS may consider you to be a chargeable overseas visitor if you need treatment in the UK. The'ordinary residence tool' and other guidelines are here https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/guidance-on-overseas-visitors-hospital-charging-regulations

Answer (score 1):

The 'other country' may consider you resident there, despite what you want them to believe. That might make you liable for paying taxes there, especially as you will be present in that country for more than 183 days per year. You also might not have to pay taxes in the UK for the same reason.

Also as mentioned in the comment to your question, your 'holiday insurance' is probably void for stays longer than 3 months. Check the policy carefully.

I would advise getting proper legal advice on the matter before buying a house. Also make sure you are legally able to own a house (and land) in that country - many countries do not allow foreigners to own houses, and the laws on property such as condos or apartments can be similarly restrictive. For example, I live in Thailand where it is strictly forbidden for a foreigner to own land - and buying a condo is a complicated process.